# An Error Was Encountered mongodb config group : get does not exist

Tags: mongodb, codeigniter

My project has four submodules. each independent CIs with same Mongodb, getting this error while trying to connect to one of submodule.

The remaining three are working fine .one module is getting this error.

while checking MongoDB error log .the error is as follows
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB not properly configured in Codeigniter. mostly occurred while creating multiple DB connection.
example :-

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '';
$db['default']['username'] = '';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = '';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

$db['secondDatabase']['hostname'] = '';
$db['secondDatabase']['username'] = '';
$db['secondDatabase']['password'] = '';
$db['secondDatabase']['dbdriver'] = '';
$db['secondDatabase']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['secondDatabase']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['secondDatabase']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['secondDatabase']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['secondDatabase']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['secondDatabase']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['secondDatabase']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['secondDatabase']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['secondDatabase']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['secondDatabase']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```